# How do you get "You might also like" results from Foursquare's API based on a venue ID?

Tags: api, foursquare

I'd like to get results like the following from Foursquare's API:

[image]

How do you get the "You might also like" venue list from Foursquare based on a particular venue ID?

Answer (score 0):

It is probably the [venues/similar](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/similar) API.

> Returns a list of venues similar to the specified venue.